# build JSON object with dynamic keys and json values

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

I am attempting to build a JSON object with a postgres query.  The output I'm looking for is similar to the object below.  The properties "xxx" and "yyy" come from a column as do the dates.

```
{
    "xxx": [ "2018-07-26T11:42:04.514Z", "2018-07-26T11:52:04.514Z"],
    "yyy": [ "2018-07-26T05:42:09.210Z", "2018-07-26T07:22:04.024Z"]
}
```

I was hoping to do this with a query similar to the one below:

```
SELECT
    json_object(
        array_agg(name),
        array_agg(json_build_array(start_date, end_date)
    )
FROM my_table
```

The my_table table would look roughly like this:

```
name | start_date                | end_date                 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
xxx  | 2018-07-26T11:42:04.514Z  | 2018-07-26T11:52:04.514Z |
yyy  | 2018-07-26T05:42:09.210Z  | 2018-07-26T07:22:04.024Z |
```

However, json_object only accepts text arrays and I can't seem to find an alternative.  So, I get `ERROR:  function json_object(text[], json[]) does not exist`.  Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_build_array()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) and [`json_object_agg().`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
select json_object_agg(name, jsonb_build_array(start_date, end_date))
from my_table
```

[DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4bd988a1ef734d7c67f040c8e2278913)